# Match first of two conditions

Tags: regex

My problem is simple, but I've been pulling my hair out trying to solve it. I have two types of strings: one has a semicolon and the other doesn't. Both have colons.

```
Reason: A chosen reason
Delete: Other: testing
Reason for action: Other; testing
Blah: Other; testing;testing
```

If the string has a semicolon, I want to match anything after the **first** one. If it has no semicolon, I want to match everything after the **first** colon. For lines above I should get:

```
A chosen reason
Other: testing
testing
testing;testing
```

I can get the semicolon to match by using `;(.*)` and I can get the colon to match by using `:(.*)`.

I tried using an alternative like this: `;(.*)|:(.*)` thinking that maybe if I have the right order I can get it to match the semicolon first, and then the colon if there is no semicolon, but it always just matched the colon.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I added another test case above to match the requirements I had stated. For strings with no semicolon, it should match the **first** colon.

Also, "Reason" could be anything, so I am clarifying that as well in the test cases.

**Second Edit**

To clarify, I'm using the POSIX Regular Expressions (using in PostgeSQL).

Comment: What should happen with `Reason: Other; testing: what!` or `Reason: Other; testing; what!`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus anything after the first semicolon should be returned.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus added edits to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: What is the regex engine? See `^(?:[^;:]*:(?!.*;)\s*(.*)|.*?;\s*(.*))`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LSdX3G/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using the POSIX engine. I need this to work in PostgreSQL. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression, maybe similar to:

```
:\s*(?:[^;\r\n]*;)?\s*(.*)$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPO6FW/1/)

Comment: This works perfectly, except I wanted to shy away from hardcoding "Reason". That was just a placeholder name. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: I like this solution better. Works if you replace `Reason` by `.*?`. https://regex101.com/r/ymmd8v/2

Comment: This works if you replace `Reason` with `.*?` as @palvarez suggested. Not only works in the demo, but also with the POSIX engine.

Comment: @gnarlybracket What should be the match for `test;test:test;test`

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a fast regex (233 steps) with no look aheads.

```
.*?:\s*(?:([^\n;]+)|.*?;\s*(.*))$
```

Check out the regex https://regex101.com/r/9gbpjW/3

UPDATED: to match any placeholder. Instead of just `Reason`

Comment: I was hoping for a regex that wouldn't hardcode "Reason", since that was just a placeholder. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: This works in the demo, but not with the POSIX engine.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to first check if the string has no `;` If there is none, then match until the first `:` and capture the rest in group 1.

In the case that there a `;` match until the first semicolon and capture the rest in group 1.

For the logic stated in the question:

- If the string has a semicolon, I want to match anything after the first one.
- If it has no semicolon, I want to match everything after the first colon

You could use:

```
^(?:(?!.*;)[^\r\n:]*:|[^;\r\n]*;)[ \t]*(.*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!.*;)` [Negative lookahead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html) (supported by Postgresql), assert string does not contain `;`
  - `[^\r\n:]*:` If that is the case, match 0+ times not `:` or a newline, then match `:`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^;\r\n]*;` Match 0+ times not `;` or newline, then match `;`
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[ \t]*` Match 0+ spaces or tabs
- `(.*)` Capturing group 1, match any char 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDbunf/1) | [Postgresql demo](https://rextester.com/UZXK25350)

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = .*?:(?(?!.*;)(.*)|.*?;(.*))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZsBsrQ/3/)

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: This one does not match after the **first** colon if there are two and no semicolons. See the second example in my edited answer.

Comment: added non-greedy check before colon, => .*?:(?(?!.*;)(.*)|.*?;(.*))   
 https://regex101.com/r/ZsBsrQ/3

Comment: This works in the demo, but not in the POSIX engine.

Comment: Please do not post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does, and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and more likely to attract upvotes.